# react-table CellProps issue with on TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-table, react-table-v7

On react-table v7, I have a table where each row is a nested object. When using TypeScript, For the properties that are not directly on the base row object, I have some issues getting the column definition array to work properly.

As seen in the example below, I get an error on the argument to the Cell formatter in the column that has a nested property (batteryModel.capacity). The error is because the type of the argument to the Cell formatter cannot be automatically inferred. However, this works fine with "externalId", since this is a direct string property on the row object.

[image: Example]

I am able to work around the issue by defining the type of the Cell formatter argument manually, but I don't think this is a good solution, as it has the potential for bugs in the future, if some of the column data types changes:

[image: Example 2]

If this is a weakness I have to live with, then maybe it would be better to preprocess the rows into a new object that flattens the structure, but this feels like unnecessary complexity. Nested row data is supported in react-table, but if it makes the  lib unable to detect the data type of the column in TypeScript, I would say it's almost unusable. So I am hoping there is a good way to make sure the data type is properly detected even on nested objects.

- [react-table docs](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/overview)

Comment: the question hasn't link for mentioned library. here is documentation link https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CellProps`

```
const EditCell = (d: CellProps<DataType>) => {
  return (
    <Link
      href={/my/path/ + d.cell.value}
      className="text-sm text-gray-500 underline hover:text-gray-900"
    >
      Edit
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Your column object could look like this

```
  const columns = useMemo<Column<DataType>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Id',
        accessor: 'id',
        Cell: EditCell
      } 
  );
```

```
type DataType = {
  id: string
}
```

[Reference for available TS interfaces (v7)](https://gist.github.com/Grsmto/1ac3a7ddb8ad8288660784a37bff1798)

Answer (score 0):

Define the entire object as a `Column[]`. Like `const columnDef: Column[] = {...}`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).